# WP-Members Avatar addition

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, avatar

Stackoverflowians,

I have scoured the internet, along with the developer's site for an answer to this... I've gotten about 75% of the way there, but I can't figure out the remaining 25%.

I would like to add a **Upload your Avatar** section to a user's profile page on my Wordpress site.  The answer that I thought was correct was this:

```
<?php
$myAv = new simple_local_avatars();
$myAv->edit_user_profile($profileuser);
?>
```

But as I found out, this code uploads the image to the site, and also it placed the avatar upload area WELL outside my profile form.

Any hints? tips? ideas?

I've placed this code inside my `<form>` tags and also modified the `$profileuser` variable to reflect the variable that is being used to specify the current user.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this plugin? [Add Local Avatar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-local-avatar/). Looks like it does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Murphy1976 have you looked at the code to see how they did it?